# determinant exponential matrix and differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras

Let $A ∈ M(n,\mathbb{C}$).

(i) Let $f(t) = det(e^{tA})$ and
$g(t) = e^{t \cdot tr(A)}$. Show that $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ both solve the first order DEQ
$u'= tr(A)u$.

(ii) Using (i), show that $\det(exp(A)) = exp(tr(A))$.

Hint: $\det(1 + εA)= 1 + εtr(A) + O(ε^2)$

Solution: to show that $g(t)$ is indeed a solution is straightforward. But how can someone show that $f(t)$ is also a solution by using the linear algebra result from the hint? Since $f(t)$ and $g(t)$ satisfy the same initial conditions the answer to (ii) is obvious.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition
$$
e^{tA}=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(I+\frac{t}{N}A\right)^N.
$$
Generally this limit has bad convergence, is not practically useful. But here it works nicely together with the determinant. Then apply the hint for $ε=\frac{t}{N}$ small enough
$$
\det(I+εA)=\prod_{i=1}^n(1+εA_{ii})+O(ε^2)=1+ε\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ii}+O(ε^2).
$$
The determinant expansion has the diagonal product, and any other product term contains at least 2 off-diagonal elements, which are proportional to $ε$.

Comment: And what is the differential of f(t)?

Comment: This line of argument shows directly that $f(t)=g(t)$, so also $f'(t)=g'(t)$. Otherwise consider the difference quotient and apply the hint directly, after extracting common factors.